# Can't add Google account on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Tags: gnome, 17.04, online-accounts

I click add Google account, enter my email and password but then blank page. Nothing happens. I don't see anything in logs.

Comment: I have the same problem. See also here:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359809 I reported the bug here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-online-accounts/+bug/1687019 Please add any information that might be useful to this bug report.

Comment: This is a confirmed bug report  with a proposed fix.  As such closing this now.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution you can login to your Google account without entering passwords and it works for online-accounts.

1. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/phone-sign-in/welcome
2. Select "Add a phone"
3. Follow the instructions
4. Open online-accounts, select Google, enter your email
5. Use your phone to add Google account to online-accounts

More information you can find here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6361026?hl=en

Comment: I was able to log in with this method but I don't see Google account added. It asked me to allow access closed the window and nothing... :(

Answer (score -1):

I am also running into the same issue.  I am wondering if it has something to do with two-step authentication. As a side note, I get these warnings in the terminal:

```
** (gnome-control-center:5425): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher gufw (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:5425): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher landscape-client-settings (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:5425): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher language-selector (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:5425): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher system-config-printer (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:5425): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher ubuntuone-installer (missing desktop file)
```

Comment: Those warnings aren't related to this bug.

Comment: Thanks.  I was getting a blank screen (the online accounts/google sign on screen) after inputing my password.  The output was to the terminal that I used to start online accounts.  I figured that they were related and apologize if they are not.

Comment: This is by no means an answer to the question.